# Jquery group element together

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic list such as

```
<span class="data-holder" data-month="1" data-year="2015" data-content="mydata"></span>
<span class="data-holder" data-month="2" data-year="2015" data-content="mydata"></span>
<span class="data-holder" data-month="3" data-year="2015" data-content="mydata"></span>
<span class="data-holder" data-month="1" data-year="2014" data-content="mydata"></span>
...
```

I am trying to display it as lists group by year as following:

```
<ul>
    <p>2015</p1>
    <li><span>1<span><span>mydata</span></li>
    <li><span>2<span><span>mydata</span></li>
    <li><span>3<span><span>mydata</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <p>2014</p1>
    <li><span>1<span><span>mydata</span></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried to loop each data-holder, and each time I try to compare the current data-year with previous data-year. If they are equals, I will the push the current data into an array. If they are not, then I will loop the through the array to construct the ul. Well, I find it is more challenging than I thought it would be. I wonder if Jquery have any function such as groupbyproperties()? If it's not, would you mind to help me to achieve my goal? 
Thank you,

Comment: There is no such feature in jQuery Core. Maybe in a plugin somewhere, but that will be yours to research. Your current algorithm is fine as long as the elements are sorted by `data-year`.

Comment: Show us what you have and we can then help you further. A suggestion would be to gather up all the years first, save them in an array, loop the array and get the elements with the same data-year.

Comment: Oh, and `<p>` elements cannot be the children of `<ul>` elements (just noticed this). You may want to change your markup accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over is good idea. You can create on `<ul>` element with class or id which you can grab later and in case it exists just append new record from your input `<span>` list. Below you have my solution ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7d92pwqt/)). Output `<ul>`s have additional id attribute, but I hope it isn't problem for yot.

```
$('.data-holder').each(function(index, item) {
    var year = $(item).attr('data-year');

    if ($('ul#year-' + year).length == 0) {
        $('body').append('<ul id=year-' + year + '>');
        $('ul#year-' + year).append('<p>' + year + '</p>');
    }

    var data = '<li><span>' + $(item).attr('data-month') + '</span><span>' + $(item).attr('data-content') +  '</span></li>';
    $('ul#year-' + year).append(data);
});
```

Comment: It is a better practice use _.data('year')_ instead of _.attr('data-year')_ ..=)